# How do I get Ruby to return an object instead of string with to_json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The docs say this:

```
{ :name => "Konata Izumi", 'age' => 16, 1 => 2 }.to_json
=> {"name": "Konata Izumi", "1": 2, "age": 16}
```

But when I actually try it in the rails console it looks like this:

```
{ :name => "Konata Izumi", 'age' => 16, 1 => 2 }.to_json
=> "{\"name\":\"Konata Izumi\",\"age\":16,\"1\":2}"
```

How do I get it to return an object/hash instead of a string? I don't want the outer quotes around the curly braces. I want `{...}` instead of `"{...}"`.

Comment: Well, then don't convert it to JSON then? `{ :name => "Konata Izumi", 'age' => 16, 1 => 2 }` this is already a hash, no need to do `to_json`.

Comment: But I need the JSON format to make a POST request, this value would be in the body of the POST request.

Comment: The outer quotes are not actually in the result JSON value, that's just the console letting you know that it's printing a string.

Comment: A string is of course an object. You may wish to change the wording of your title and text.

Answer (score 3):

```rb
irb(main):012:0> x = { :name => "Konata Izumi", 'age' => 16, 1 => 2 }.to_json
irb(main):013:0> puts x
{"name":"Konata Izumi","age":16,"1":2}
=> nil
```

If you capture the results in a variable and then print it, you'll see that it is working as expected. The quotes are just the console's way of indicating that the stuff after `=>` is a string.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a format for serializing data *to text*. It simply *is* a `String`, it cannot be anything else, that would be non-sensical.

If you want to keep a Ruby object instead of serializing to a string, simply don't serialize to a string.